# Oriented Bordism Group and Un-Oriented Bordism Group of points $pt$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces, cobordism

> Do we know, or are there any References that list down complete oriented and unoriented Bordism Group $Ω_{n,O}(pt)$ and $Ω_{n,SO}(pt)$ of points $pt$ for dimensions $n=1,2,...,10$?

Here are some informations I know. And a useful Ref is [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/cobord.pdf).

$$Ω_{1,O}(pt) =0,$$
$$Ω_{2,O}(pt) =\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$$
$$Ω_{3,O}(pt) = 0,$$ 
$$Ω_{4,O}(pt) =\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$$
$$Ω_{5,O}(pt) =\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$$
$$Ω_{6,O}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{7,O}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{8,O}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{9,O}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{10,O}(pt) =?,$$

---

$$Ω_{1,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{2,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{3,SO}(pt) = ?,$$ 
$$Ω_{4,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{5,SO}(pt) =\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}?$$
$$Ω_{6,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{7,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{8,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{9,SO}(pt) =?,$$
$$Ω_{10,SO}(pt) =?,$$

Comment: The unoriented case is completely determined by Thom, the oriented case is by Wall in the reference you give (p.293).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unoriented cobordism: can be read off from the structure of the [unoriented cobordism ring](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Unoriented_bordism#Construction_and_examples) (calculated in Thom's thesis): $\Omega_6^O = (\mathbb Z/2)^3$, $\Omega_7^O = \mathbb Z/2$, $\Omega_8^O = (\mathbb Z/2)^5$, $\Omega_9^O = (\mathbb Z/2)^3$, and $\Omega_{10}^O = (\mathbb Z/2)^8$.

Oriented cobordism: in Milnor and Stasheff, *Characteristic Classes*, end of §17, p. 203. $\Omega_1^{SO} = 0$, $\Omega_2^{SO} = 0$, $\Omega_3^{SO} = 0$, $\Omega_4^{SO} = \mathbb Z$, $\Omega_5^{SO} = \mathbb Z/2$, $\Omega_6^{SO} = \Omega_7^{SO} = 0$, $\Omega_8^{SO} = \mathbb Z^2$, $\Omega_9^{SO} = (\mathbb Z/2)^2$, and $\Omega_{10}^{SO} = \mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: Thanks, +1, are you saying that my above results from dimensions 1 to 5 coincide for unoriented cobordism and oriented cobordism? And my answers above were correct for 1 to 5?

Comment: Yes, everything you stated in your question is correct. I didn't see that you were missing the lower-dimensional oriented cobordism groups; I'll go ahead and edit them into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, +1, could you explain the unmatching relations between the $O$ and $SO$ for two sets of bordism groups? What is the intuition behind?
 Thanks!

Comment: @wonderich I don't know what the unmatching relations are, and Google didn't help me at all, so you'll probably get more luck asking a separate question with a reference.